# Column existent but sometimes prompted as not there

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

First I ran

```
SELECT * 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = '[Tablename]'
```

to know which columns to convert into another format via

```
ALTER TABLE [tablename] 
ALTER COLUMN [columnname] [format]
```

Problem: I get the following prompt for a column listed by the first command line:

> Msg 4924, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN failed because column '[Columnname]' does not exist in table '[Tablename]'.

Trying to convert the column from `FLOAT` to `DECIMAL(19,12)` doesn't work, but I did that with other columns of the same table before successfully.

Appreciate the input as always!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out funnily enough right after posting it. Had been debating about it for a while beforehand. My column name actually started with a space, was not aware that this was even possible.